# VTune 2013 Profiler giving Error: “The Data Cannot be displayed,there is no viewpoint available for data ”

Tags: c, optimization, profiler, intel-vtune

I want to optimize my code which is written in C but this error is always displayed “The Data Cannot be displayed,there is no viewpoint available for data ”, am working on windows XP and the profiler is update 2!

Comment: Are you running inside a VM ?

Comment: What do you mean by a VM?
Am so sorry am still learning am in grade 10!

Comment: Are you running inside a Virtual Machine, e.g. VMware ?

Comment: Oh!
NO am not actually!

Answer (score 1):

There must be some error cropping up which is causing the executable to not run properly which is causing this issue. In my case, it was not able to resolve path for a .a file.

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like a bug during collection stage. It is likely that result directory is missing some data due to collection error. Try to update to latest update 15 and repeat your experiment. If issue is still there you may wan to contact support team for investigation http://software.intel.com/en-us/forums/intel-vtune-amplifier-xe-and-vtune-performance-analyzer. Also make sure you XP has latest Service Pack (3?) installed